# IP Scan Power Shell Script

Tags: powershell

I'm trying creating a powershell script to ping a range of **IP** by enter the first and last octet. If `Write-host` is used the rest of the script won't execute. If write output is used the `..` doesn't work as a sequence

```
$StartIP = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input Start IP'

$EndIP = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input End IP'

Write-output $StartIP..$EndIP | % {"192.168.128.$($_): $(Test-Connection -count 1 -comp 192.168.128.$($_) -quiet)"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enclose it in parentheses:

```
Write-output ($StartIP..$EndIP) | % {"192.168.128.$($_): $(Test-Connection -count 1 -comp 192.168.128.$($_) -quiet)"}
```

If you omit Write-Output you can simple use:

```
$StartIP..$EndIP | % {"192.168.1.$($_): $(Test-Connection -count 1 -comp 192.168.1.$($_) -quiet)"}
```

Comment: Is working perfect! Now I'm try  to get the reply with true on green and false on red. Any help will be great

Comment: Please open a new questionfor that @papa0s0